# An SPI class of type org.apache.lucene.codecs.DocValuesFormat with name 'Memory' does not exist

Tags: java, lucene

Getting error:

```
Diag message: User class threw exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An SPI class of type org.apache.lucene.codecs.DocValuesFormat with name 'Memory' does not exist.
You need to add the corresponding JAR file supporting this SPI to your classpath.
The current classpath supports the following names: [Lucene54]
      at org.apache.lucene.util.NamedSPILoader.lookup(NamedSPILoader.java:116)
      at org.apache.lucene.codecs.DocValuesFormat.forName(DocValuesFormat.java:108)
```

I have tried running the jar with various newer versions of lucene-core (along with backward-compatibility jar) but no success. Currently, we are using 6.5.0 version.
The Lucene-index we are trying to read contains files like - _4o08_Memory_0.mdvd & _4o08_Memory_0.mdvm which are the real issue.

Answer (score 0):

Solution - add maven dependency  https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.lucene/lucene-codecs/6.5.0 & make sure its a runtime dependency & not limited to test scope.